# How and Where can I find information to which organization I was enrolled?

Tags: ipad, apple-id, remote-control, hacking, mdm

[image]I clicked on settings then VPN & Device Management. I was checking my VPN and noticed sign in to your school or work account. I did and I received this prompt. Apple can and will not give me any answers. [image]

Comment: If you don't know which places you enrolled to then who should?

Comment: Is this iPad from a school or business/company? Or did you buy it used?

Comment: Bye Solar Mike 

Comment: agarza I bought it new

Comment: Do you actually **have** a work or school account? If not, how are you hoping to sign into one? If you do, then ask their IT department for help in connecting.

Comment: Tetsujin I’m enrolled, but I did not do it

Comment: There is nothing in your post that indicates prior enrolment. That is just the standard 'I'm not signed into anything yet' screen.